# Ruby Net/SFTP throttle speed

Tags: ruby, sftp, net-sftp

Is there a way to throttle the connection of a transfer with the ruby [Net/SFTP](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/sftp/v2/api/) library? I would like to leverage this to download some backups on a nightly basis, but don't want to eat up all of the server's bandwidth while doing so.

Comment: @theTinMan only thing that I had come to was doing QOS on **all** ssh connections, which didn't do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this sample from the Net::SFTP documentation:

```
# open and read from a pseudo-IO for a remote file
sftp.file.open("/path/to/remote", "r") do |f|
  puts f.gets
end
```

What would happen if you put a `sleep` inside that block?

Comment: looks like this does the trick! Thanks, that's an ingenuitive way to do things